# Why getting allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level error after uploading into sub directory of a server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

I have an asp.net web project which I want to publish under a sub-directory of a hosting site. But after publishing I am getting this error:

```
**Server Error in '/' Application.**
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to 
service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your 
configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition=
'MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual 
 directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

I have created this sub folder by myself into the server location using FileZilla as I can only access the server with FTP. But if I publish this under the main directory then it does not create any issues. Please help me on this.

Comment: In IIS Manager make the sub directory an application.